# AS3: Large number of timers lagging flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, optimization, actionscript, timer

I have a large number of objects (472) that require a timer used to check how long it takes between state changes of a variable. The code below is what I have so far but that many timers running definitely impacts the performance of the application, is there a better optimised way of measuring this?

```
import flash.utils.Timer;

var active_:Boolean;
var matched:Boolean;
var vacated:Boolean;

var circ:Shape=new Shape();
this.addChild(circ);
circ.x = 0;
circ.y = 0;
var circRad:Number = 5;
var mat= new Matrix();
var busyColors = [0xFFFF00,0xFFCC00];
var idleColors = [0xCCCCCC,0x000000];
var matchedColors = [0x0099FF,0x0066FF];
var vacatedColors = [0xFF0000,0x990000];
var busyAlphas = [1,1];
var idleAlphas = [0.5,0.5];
var ratios = [0,255];
var prev:int = 0;
var time:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);
//time.start();
mat.createGradientBox(2*circRad,2*circRad,0,-circRad,-circRad);
circ.graphics.lineStyle();
if (active_ == false)
{
    if (prev != 0)
    {
        setAverage(prev,false);
        prev = 0;
    }
    circ.graphics.clear();
    circ.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL,idleColors,idleAlphas,ratios,mat);
    circ.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,circRad);
    circ.graphics.endFill();
}
else if (active_ == true && matched == true)
{
    if (prev != 1)
    {
        setAverage(prev,true);
        prev = 1;
    }
    circ.graphics.clear();
    circ.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL,matchedColors,busyAlphas,ratios,mat);
    circ.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,circRad);
    circ.graphics.endFill();
}
else if (active_ == true && vacated == false && matched == false)
{
    if (prev != 2)
    {
        setAverage(prev,true);
        prev = 2;
    }
    circ.graphics.clear();
    circ.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL,busyColors,busyAlphas,ratios,mat);
    circ.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,circRad);
    circ.graphics.endFill();
}
else if (active_ == true && vacated == true)
{
    if (prev != 3)
    {
        setAverage(prev,true);
        prev = 3;
    }
    circ.graphics.clear();
    circ.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL,vacatedColors,busyAlphas,ratios,mat);
    circ.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,circRad);
    circ.graphics.endFill();
}

function setAverage(i:int, a:Boolean)
{
    time.stop();
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0 :
            break;

        case 1 :
            MovieClip(root).avgMat.push(uint(time.currentCount));
            break;

        case 2 :
            MovieClip(root).avgBusy.push(uint(time.currentCount));
            break;

        case 3 :
            MovieClip(root).avgVac.push(uint(time.currentCount));
            break;
    }
    if(a == true){
        //time.reset();
        //time.start();
    }   
}
```

Commented out the timer starts because of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can make public function like "tick()" at yours objects and call it in loop from 1 general timer outside.

Comment: If the objects are not created at the same time, is it not inaccurate to use 'tick' to count seconds? He would probably need a different time indicator for each instance.

Comment: Exactly, every single thing is a separate instance, the only way I can think of going about it is making a single timer on the root and taking the difference each time.

Comment: You can have timer with 1/30 sec interval and check "frame expiration" before tick. It will be more frequently, but not so expansive like timers.

Comment: I've managed to set up what I mentioned above with a single timer, except I cant seem to be able to push the values back to an array on the root. If I specify `MovieClip(root)` that will go to the highest point yes?

Comment: I'd say use a single enter frame listener in any of your objects, this way you can always access stage. And use that listener to call a `tick()` like suggested on anything available to you - you will need an array of these or alike, and maintain it throughout your process.

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing the following:

in the top, import getTimer

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
```

Create a variable containing the starting time (instead of doing timer.start) do this:

```
var timerStart : int = getTimer();
```

and instead of doing this: time.currentCount

Simply do this:

```
(getTimer() - timerStart) / 1000
```

Good luck.

Comment: Solved my issue. Timer.currentCound is INCORRECT in mobile devices especially, when using Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 0):

you could change all the timers with addEventListener of type EVENT FRAME

```
var counter:Number = 0;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, counting);
function counting (e:Event):void
{
     counter++
}
```

So counter will increment on every frame. Now you have to find fps. Now multiply fps by time that you want timer to run after. So it's should look like this:

```
var counter:Number = 0;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, counting);
function counting (e:Event):void
{
     counter++
     if(counter == 60) //60 fps means this line will run after 1 sec.
     {
          //do something
     }
     If(counter == 120) //60 fps; 2 sec
     {
          //do something
     }
}
```

This method is much more accurate and the system will not be so overloaded. This can especcially help you for setting up the stage using addChild, when you need a delay after the animation is started.

You can make more of this 'timers', but that depends on the demands of the game, but i'm sure that it will work faster than hundreths of timers.

Comment: See the problem with that method is that if the application lags, so does the timing. Also I think there is confusion with what I need to happen. Basically I have ~470 "nodes" which each have one of 4 states. I need to log the amount of time these nodes stay in 3 of these states, in an array. Then an average function run on the array to return a single averaged value.